# my coreos/fleet deployed service is dying and I can't tell why

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm trying to deploy nsqlookupd using fleet on a brand shiny new coreos cluster in EC2. Here is my systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=nsqlookupd service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill nsqlookupd
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm nsqlookupd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -d --name=nsqlookupd -e BROADCAST_ADDRESS=$COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4 -p 4160:4160 -p 4161:4161 mikedewar/nsqlookupd
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /nsqlookupd_broadcast_address $COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 1 nsqlookupd
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /nsqlookupd_broadcast_address
```

I've verified the container works fine if I just run the `ExecStart` command. My docker logs just look like

```
~ $ docker logs nsqlookupd
2014/08/08 02:23:58 nsqlookupd v0.2.29-alpha (built w/go1.2.2)
2014/08/08 02:23:58 TCP: listening on [::]:4160
2014/08/08 02:23:58 HTTP: listening on [::]:4161
```

and my fleetctl journal looks like

```
$ fleetctl journal nsqlookupd.service
-- Logs begin at Sun 2014-08-03 12:49:00 UTC, end at Fri 2014-08-08 02:30:06 UTC. --
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 systemd[1]: Starting nsqlookupd service...
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6140]: Error response from daemon: No such container: nsqlookupd
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6140]: 2014/08/08 02:23:57 Error: failed to kill one or more containers
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6148]: Error response from daemon: No such container: nsqlookupd
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6148]: 2014/08/08 02:23:57 Error: failed to remove one or more containers
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 etcdctl[6157]: 54.198.93.169
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 systemd[1]: Started nsqlookupd service.
Aug 08 02:23:57 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6155]: 0fce4465f61c092541ba9d4c4e89ce13c4d6bedc096519034ed585d7adb5e0d7
Aug 08 02:23:59 ip-10-147-9-249 docker[6194]: nsqlookupd
```

both of which look just fine. But the container dies quietly, and my fleetctl list-units gives

```
$ fleetctl list-units
UNIT                STATE       LOAD    ACTIVE          SUB     DESC                MACHINE
nsqlookupd.service  launched    loaded  deactivating    stop    nsqlookupd service  1320802c.../10.147.9.249
```

Running `docker images` is a little worrying:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>                 <none>              8ef9d8f9d18d        9 minutes ago       710 MB
mikedewar/nsqadmin     latest              432af572bda8        2 days ago          710 MB
mikedewar/nsqd         latest              00bd4e474964        2 days ago          710 MB
<none>                 <none>              adf0ed97208e        3 weeks ago         710 MB
mikedewar/nsqlookupd   latest              2219c0e783d9        3 weeks ago         710 MB
<none>                 <none>              35d2212f8932        3 weeks ago         710 MB
mikedewar/nsq          latest              f9794fe056e1        3 weeks ago         710 MB
busybox                latest              a9eb17255234        9 weeks ago         2.433 MB
zmarcantel/cassandra   latest              b1168b45b4f8        4 months ago        738 MB
```

as I've been updating mikedewar/nsqlookupd quite regularly over the last 3 weeks. Maybe that's the time I first pushed something to docker hub? I'd love to know that the image I'm working with is the up-to-date one. I've tried `docker rmi mikedewar/nsqlookupd` followed by `docker pull mikedewar/nsqlookupd` but the `CREATED` column still says it was created 3 weeks ago.

I don't know if this is useful, but the `ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /nsqlookupd_broadcast_address` command seems to have worked - the `etcdctl` log line in the fleet journal suggests I managed to set the key to my IP, but after the container dies I can't get that key from etcd.

Any help on where to look next for clues, or any ideas why this is happening would be greatly appreciated! As is probably clear I'm rather new to this sort of thing...

Comment: you can try to execute `docker images` and `docker ps` to verify if mikedewar/nsqlookupd image it's present?

Comment: err so docker images is a little worrying. Editing question...

Comment: `docker ps` doesn't show the container running as it dies immediately, but `docker ps -a` does show that a container existed for a moment.

Comment: ok...are you sure that `mikedewar/nsqlookupd` image are right? to verify execute `docker pull mikedewar/nsqlookupd` and `docker run mikedewar/nsqlookupd` out site of CoreOS.

Comment: Note: usually when I write a service to run with fleet I specify docker pull sentences. For your case: `ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker pull mikedewar/nsqlookupd`.

Comment: should `docker pull` overwrite existing images?

Comment: have verified that `mikedewar/nsqlookupd` is fine inside a seperate boot2docker VM on my laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58966/discussion-between-kikicarbonell-and-mike-dewar).

Comment: initially your coreos node have not a `mikedewar/nsqlookupd` then you need execute `docker pull <image>` to download image to local node
please, try to login on via ssh on your coreos node and remove <image> resources with: `docker rmi <image>` and then, execute `fleetctl submit nsqlookupd.service` and `fleetctl start nsqlookupd.service`

Comment: Note: I found innecesary sentences on your services: `ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill nsqlookupd` and `ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm nsqlookupd`, try to remove and redeploy service

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't run docker containers in detached mode in a unit file. Your execstart contains it: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -d`. This will cause systemd to think the process exited immediately since it was forked into the background.

As for managing versions, if you want to be absolutely sure you're getting the latest copy, you should tag your containers and then pull mikedewar/nsqlookupd:1.2.3. You can increment this each time in your fleet unit file.

Comment: this explains everything. Thanks so much!

Comment: thanks also to @kikicarbonell who has spent quite a lot of effort having me tidy up my approach!

Comment: OMG! I have finally found your answer. It was a long day. Thank you very much.